# How does the UnaryFunction look like in std::for_each

Tags: c++, std

I am playing with *std::for_each*, I could understand the following:

```
std::vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int& n) {
  n++;
});
```

According to the definition, It's not hard to deduct the UnaryFunction f.

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f);
```

However, when I have a vector of threads

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
```

I am fascinated by this particular line of code which blocks and waits for the execution to finish:

```
std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join))
```

How does it work? What's the UnaryFunction in this case? **std::thread::join** takes no parameters so it's not a unary function. What magic does the **std::mem_fn** do to create the unary function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread::join` *does* actually take one parameter - it is the hidden (implied) `this` parameter of type `std::thread *`. The same is true for any non-static member function: it actually has one more parameter than explicitly declared. `std::mem_fn` "unhides" the implied `this` parameter, turning it into a visible parameter.

So, `std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join)` is indeed an unary function with one parameter of `std::thread *` type. The resultant function object implements standard `INVOKE` behavior, meaning that it is also callable with `std::thread &` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Basically - it is equivalent to this:

```
std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread& t) { t.join(); })
```

So the `std::mem_fun(<ref to member function>)` generates a functor which accepts a reference to an instance of the type, and when called with that instance, calls the referenced member function.

Comment: `std::mem_fn` is not deprecated in C++17. Perhaps you mean the [deprecated overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)?

Comment: There's no use of `std::mem_fun` in the question.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi mem_fn is needed to call the join member function in the original question.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld yes, and it is not `std::mem_fun` (as @Nim stated; I assume it's a typo) , because it doesn't exist. It is `std::mem_fn`. And `std::mem_fn` is not deprecated.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi oh oh. yeah it's not fun :)